# Javascript - correct way to wait for super long loop?

Tags: javascript

Maybe this is an async / await situation but I thought async was mainly for api calls(?)

How do you wait a long loop to finish, like this:

```
let x;
for (i = 1, i < 10000000000000000, i++) {
  x += (i * 99999);
}

console.log(x);
```

Comment: There isn't an asynchronous operation here. The loop happens synchronously, so you "wait" but just not being able to do anything on the in the same execution environment until this finishes. Take note that *all the execution* will have to wait for this, nothing else would work.

Comment: *"How do you wait a long loop to finish"* I usually get a coffee

Comment: is this a dad joke or a programming one

Comment: @BenCoupe the answer is: yes

Comment: @VLAZ Awesome, thank you. I didn't realize that. Is there anything that's is asynchronous that is not a network call?

Comment: @KirkRoss file system access, delegating a call to an external library, database calls, reading and processing files (e.g., parsing XML) are all common operations that can be done asynchronously. In general, any task that will take indeterminate amount of time (e.g., 1ms or 100ms) can be represented asynchronously to reduce the delays needed when processing that.

Comment: @Cid that's a bit misleading, since asynchronous functions are processed synhronously until either an `await` is encountered or a `return`. At that point, they delay the execution and produce a promise. So `async function() { doHeavySynchronousOperation() }` will block the thread until `doHeavySynchronousOperation` finishes and only then do you get a promise back that will resolve to `undefined`.

Comment: Assuming the example is heavily simplified (the resulted number is far beyond the maximum number JS can present), and you really have a time-consuming task, delegate it to a web worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought async was mainly for api calls(?)

There are two different concepts related to the `async` word:

- `async/await` functions
  Syntax sugar for receive Promises results in syncronous manner
- real asynchronous behavior
  XHR api calls, delayed execution, event handling

`async/await` function does not make your function execution asynchronous automagically.

```js
const foo = async (i) => { console.log('foo running', i); return i == 0 ? 42 : await foo(i-1); };
console.log('foo before')
foo(5)
  .then(x => console.log('foo', x))
console.log('foo after')

// foo before
// foo running 5
// foo running 4
// foo running 3
// foo running 2
// foo running 1
// foo running 0
// foo after
// foo 42
```

Javascript is one-threaded, all concurrent tasks must be splitted into async chunks to have any chance to other to work.

So, you should split your sync loop to many async parts to not to be frozen.

For example(*I reduce params to have not too much time for wait*):

```js
async function calcX() {
  let x = 0;
  function iteration(i) {
    x += (i * 99999);
    if (++i >= 10000) return Promise.resolve(x);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => iteration(i).then(resolve), 0);
      // or requestAnimationFrame
    });
  }
  return await iteration(1);
}
const start = Date.now();
calcX()
  .then(x => console.log(x, Date.now() - start), err => console.error(err));

// 4999450005000 42465
```

It can be too slow if you put each iteration to event loop. So you can optimize it by batching of them(see @Steve's answer)

<sub>Or use WebWorker for your heavy sync task</sub>

Comment: "*Definitely, no. Each setTimeout or addEventListener in your code is async as well.*" but not nearly the same way as an async function and these two have nothing to do with promises. So while they *are* async it's kind of a different concept to where you'll use `async` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert long running synchronous functions into asynchronous functions by checking to see if a set amount of time has elapsed, and then coming back to the function later (achieved in this example via `setTimeout`):

```js
var lastBreak = Date.now()

function takeABreak() {
    return new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve));
}

async function maybeTakeABreak() {
    if (Date.now() - 17 > lastBreak) {
        lastBreak = Date.now();
        await takeABreak();
    }
}

async function myLongLoop() {
    let x = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < 100000000000000; i++) {
       await maybeTakeABreak();
       x += (i * 99999);
       if (!(i%1000000)) {
          console.log(i);
          // alternatively you could run `await takeABreak();` here
       }
    }
    return x;
}
myLongLoop().then(x=>console.log(x));
```